# cocoapods lint - Encountered an unknown error

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, cocoapods, podspec

I Hope someone can help me out here, I'm going nuts!

I had a working SDK submitted to Cocoapods and now lint is not building properly.

Here is my PodSpec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'SpotIM'
  s.version          = '1.1.9'
  s.summary          = 'This SDK allows you to integrate SpotIM into your iOS app.'
  s.description      = <<-DESC

## Welcome to the Spot.IM SDK

Spot.IM SDK provides an easy integration with [Spot.IM](http://www.spot.im) into a native iOS app.

Here's a sample app that shows how to use the Spot.IM SDK for iOS.

## Getting started

To use the SDK you will need an active Spot.IM account. If you don't have it, get one [here](http://www.spot.im).
You will need to know your Spot ID (which looks like 'sp_xxxxxxx').
If you don't know your Spot ID, login to the [admin dashboard](https://admin.spot.im) and have a look at the URL.

DESC

  s.homepage        = "http://www.spot.im"
  s.screenshots     = 'https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/607917/35287547-4076605c-006b-11e8-9674-a1c9e4f8f681.png', 'https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/607917/35287551-423452be-006b-11e8-96e9-7bf7a3ae27b6.png', 'https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/607917/35287552-4259dc5a-006b-11e8-9a27-c14b37a5a32b.png'
  s.license         = { :type => 'CUSTOM', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author          = { 'Hernan Arber' => 'hernan@spot.im' }
  s.platform     = :ios
   s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'

# the Pre-Compiled Framework:
 s.source          = { :http => 'https://github.com/SpotIM/iOS-prod/files/1674195/Spot_IM.framework.zip' }
  s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'Spot_IM.framework'

end
```

the PodSpec was previously working, gave me:

Congrats
   SpotIM (1.1.8) successfully published

But now When I Run:

```
pod lib lint SpotIM.podspec --no-clean --verbose
```

I'm Getting:

```
    - ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (No such file or directory @ realpath_rec - /Users/MY_USER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Spot_IM-boxujpqdtoaazagkfyxibultxifq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/project.rb:190:in `realpath'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/project.rb:190:in `realpath'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/project.rb:190:in `add_file_reference'.... // And So On!
```

I already Tried doing:

```
sudo rm -fr ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
pod setup
```

But it didn't solve the Problem...

PLEASE HELP ME!

Thanks

Comment: Try rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/

Comment: Thanks bro Will do

Comment: Ok So It Didn't work... I Stil get this message:     - ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (No such file or directory @ realpath_rec - /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Spot_IM-boxujpqdtoaazagkfyxibultxifq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates

Answer (score 0):

I Found the way to Submit the Compiled SDK to Cocoapods, here is the Final Podspec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'SpotIM'
  s.version          = '1.2.1'
  s.summary          = 'This SDK allows you to integrate SpotIM into your iOS app.'
  s.description      = <<-DESC

## Welcome to the Spot.IM SDK

Spot.IM SDK provides an easy integration with [Spot.IM](http://www.spot.im) into a native iOS app.

Here's a sample app that shows how to use the Spot.IM SDK for iOS.

## Getting started

To use the SDK you will need an active Spot.IM account. If you don't have it, get one [here](http://www.spot.im).
You will need to know your Spot ID (which looks like 'sp_xxxxxxx').
If you don't know your Spot ID, login to the [admin dashboard](https://admin.spot.im) and have a look at the URL.

DESC

  s.homepage        = "http://www.spot.im"
  s.screenshots     = 'https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/607917/35287547-4076605c-006b-11e8-9674-a1c9e4f8f681.png', 'https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/607917/35287551-423452be-006b-11e8-96e9-7bf7a3ae27b6.png', 'https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/607917/35287552-4259dc5a-006b-11e8-9a27-c14b37a5a32b.png'
  s.license         = { :type => 'CUSTOM', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author          = { 'Hernan Arber' => 'hernan@spot.im' }
  s.platform     = :ios
  s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'

# the Pre-Compiled Framework:
  s.source          = { :http => 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/spot.im.artifacts/ios/Latest/Spot_IM.framework.zip' }
  s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'Spot_IM.framework'

end
```